# HTML - JavaScript get copy to clipboard?

Tags: javascript, html

```
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = PosX;
document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = PosY;
<p><span id="x"></span>,<span id="y"></span></p>
```

How can I get copy to clipboard. This <p> value?

Could you help me? Thanks..

```
navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
```

I read almost all post about it. And, I just found this code. However, I didn't understand how can I use it.

Comment: This may help: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to first select the `<p>` element and get its value. For example:

```js
let copyText = document.querySelector("p").innerText;
navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText).then(() => {
    console.log("Copied to clipboard!");
}).catch(error => {
    console.error("Failed to copy: ", error);
});
```

In this example, document.querySelector("p") selects the first `<p>` element on the page, and innerText gets its text content. Then, the writeText method is used to copy the text to the clipboard, and the .then and .catch methods are used to handle success and error cases, respectively.

Comment: @Dev.T, I’m glad to help, if my answer helped, you can mark it as correct and vote for my answer

Comment: Of course. Thanks. But I didn't use this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button that when clicked, will copy the text in the

element to the clipboard. Here's an example:

```
<p><span id="x"></span>,<span id="y"></span></p>
<button id="copy-btn">Copy to Clipboard</button>

<script>
  document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = PosX;
  document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = PosY;

  let copyBtn = document.getElementById("copy-btn");
  copyBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let copyText = document.querySelector("p");
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.innerText).then(function() {
      console.log("Copied to clipboard");
    }, function(err) {
      console.error("Could not copy text: ", err);
    });
  });
</script>
```

When the user clicks the "Copy to Clipboard" button, the text in the

element will be copied to the clipboard.

Comment: Can we also copy to clipboard with mouse click also. Thanks @Bryce Fountain